# Set observable property of object by path

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, lodash

I have an object that could have any number of levels and could have any existing properties. Besides, the object and/or its properties may be observable.
For example:

```
var obj = {
    prop: "qqq",
    obsProp: ko.observable({
      nestedObsProp: ko.observable({
       prop: 'value'
      })
    })
};
```

I need to have a way to set all properties (both observable and non-observables) of any nested levels in a way something like this:

```
set(obj, 'obsProp.nestedObsProp.prop', 'new value');
```

I tried to use lodash function `_.set()`, it works only if properties are not observables, but properties in `obj` (which I have to update) can be both - observable or not.
I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function set (source, key, newValue) {
    const hierarchy = key.split('.');
    const property = hierarchy.pop();

    const retrived = hierarchy.reduce((source, key) => {
        return source[key];
    }, source) || source;

    if (ko.isObservable(retrived[property])) {
        retrived[property](newValue);
    } else {
        retrived[property] = newValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[yoel neuman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4471267/yoel-neuman), thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot. I took your function as base approach with small corrections:

```
function set(source, path, newValue) {
    const hierarchy = path.split('.');
    const property = hierarchy.pop();

    var retrieved = hierarchy.reduce((source, key) => {
        return ko.isObservable(source) ? source()[key] : source[key];
    }, source) || source;

    retrieved = ko.isObservable(retrieved) ? retrieved() : retrieved;
    if (ko.isObservable(retrieved[property])) {
        retrieved[property](newValue);
    } else {
        retrieved[property] = newValue;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I have not enough reputation to vote for your answer. Much appreciated your help!